# I am trying to answer Y to my SSM document automatically that uses shell script

Tags: shell, aws-ssm

The line "sudo apt autoremove nessusagent" asks for prompt Y/n I always have to say Y. Trying to find a way to do automatically I tried to add <<- Y  at the end of the command it didn't work.

---

schemaVersion: "2.2"
description: "Command Document Example JSON Template"
parameters:
Message:
type: "String"
description: "Hello World!"
default: "Hello"
mainSteps:

- action: "aws:runShellScript"
  name: "HelloScript"
  inputs:
  runCommand:

  - "sudo apt autoremove nessusagent &&"
  - "sleep 20 &&"
  - "echo 'uninstallation completed!'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an option for that

```
sudo apt autoremove --yes nessusagent
```

See `man apt-get`

Answer (score 0):

The below code helped me to get over with the prompt.

```
echo 'Y' | sudo apt autoremove nessusagent
```